# Drop all rows in a data frame from first match through to last row

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I'd like to drop all the rows in a data frame from the first row that matches a condition through to the last row.

This is what I've got in base R, to find the row where `disp` is 400, and drop that row and all the rows from that row to the last row:

```
mtcars[-c(which(mtcars$disp == 400):nrow(mtcars)), ]
```

How can I do this with dplyr and/or data.table?

Comment: `head(mtcars, match(400, mtcars$disp)-1)` too

Comment: Also note that your code is a bit clunky in that `which` returns all matches for `400` and then only the first is used in the `:` sequence. Note the warning on `mtcars[-c(which(mtcars$disp==360):nrow(mtcars)),]`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Starting from the first match is fine since that's actually the goal here, as I wrote in the Q "first match through to last row".

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Starting from the first match is fine since that's actually the goal here, as I wrote in the Q "first match through to last row".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can use `cumsum` inside `filter`. Once you hit the first 400, cumsum increases to one.

```
mtcars%>%
  filter(cumsum(disp==400)<1)
```

Here's the equivalent in `data.table`:

```
mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[cumsum(disp==400)<1]
```